# how to set focus the dropdown item in the page load event?

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, pageload

Based on my dataset row value , my drop drown will focus the particular list item in page load event.

ddparty.SelectedIndex = ddparty.Items.IndexOf(ddparty.Items.FindByValue(ds.Tables[2].Rows[0][1].ToString()));

i try the above code its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the property:

mydropdown.SelectedItem

or
mydropdown.SelectedValue

Make sure you do this AFTER databinding the dropdown control.

Comment: ddparty.SelectedIndex = ddparty.Items.IndexOf(ddparty.Items.FindByValue(ds.Tables[2].Rows[0][1].ToString()));
is this correct

Comment: Yes, this is how you do it by hand :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you've set your DataValueField to the datatable's second column. On the other hand if you've set your DataTextField to it, try FindByText instead of FindByValue.

As a side note, try to quickwatch in the debugger, the value of the index you get.